# What's is difference between python-ldap modrdn method and rename method?

Tags: python, ldap

modrdn method can modify cn attribute and rename method also works, so, what's the difference between them? and which attributes belong to "rdn" attributes？

Answer (score 0):

For one, the arguments that you can pass to them.  And, as a consequence, the exact operation; e.g., `rename()` has the note "The optional parameter newsuperior is used to specify a new parent DN for moving an entry in the tree".  There are further differences, as well.

This is from https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html, the first hit in a Google search for your exact question, "What's is difference between python-ldap modrdn method and rename method?".

You are new to Stack Overflow; please be aware that SO works best when people asking questions conduct their own research first, and can therefore ask a question about the parts they cannot figure out on their own.

As a welcome new user, you will want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);  if you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem;  also, remember to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);  people will be glad to help.